# HTML Input only allow values that's part of the step attribute

Tags: html, input, numbers

Is there a way to prevent a user from entering values that's not part of the html input `step` attribute?

I have this basic HTML input:

```
<input type="number" step="10" />
```

Basically when the user clicks the increment, it will increment the input to 10,20,30,40,50.
But for this example, the user will have a ability to enter numbers that's not part of the step value.

User could input: 24,25,26,37,38,39 etc. which breaks the step rule.

Any help on how to prevent this?

Comment: I think you have to use something like Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function validateInput(input) {
  var value = parseFloat(input.value);
  if (value % 10 !== 0 && input.value.length >= 2) {
    input.value = (Math.floor(value/10) + 1) * 10;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="10" oninput="validateInput(this)" />
```

Comment: I tried entering a value like 30, but it doesn't allow me

Comment: The problem is that when you type 30, the first value the program recognizes is 3, which is not a multiple of 10, and it resets the value to 0 before letting you complete the value. I will try to fix this code.

Comment: I have edited the code, can you test it and see if this is what you're looking for?